# HTML/Javascript How to get a Range object matching a textbox or textarea selection?

Tags: javascript, html, selection

Using Typescript (or Javascript), I need to dynamically create and position a DOM node immediately beneath the caret (blinking cursor) while the user is focused in a textbox, textarea or contenteditable div.

I got the contenteditable div part to work with something like this:

```
const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
const left: number = rect.left;
const top: number = rect.top + rect.height;

myElement.style.position = 'absolute';
myElement.style.top = `${top}px`;
myElement.style.left = `{left}px`;
```

This works like a charm.  Problem is that `document.getSelection` does not give me the selection I want within a textbox or textarea.  In my research I've come across the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties, but these don't give the screen coordinates of the caret, which is what I need to dynamically position `myElement`.

So my question can be simplified to:  how do I get the coordinates of the caret (or more exactly, a bounding rectangle of the selected text) in a textbox or textarea?

Comment: you can't insert a node in texture or input. it works with content editable element coz its a element not an input

Comment: @joyBlanks I don't want to insert a node _inside_ the text input.  I just need the location of the caret so I can create the node and display it underneath the input (or overlaid for textarea) but aligned with the caret.  They would be siblings, not parent-child.